# Java boolean method return

Tags: java, netbeans, boolean

I have a boolean method in my Java program and I'm wondering why NetBeans is recommending making this change to my code:

```
return isPrime != 0;
```

What I wrote was:

```
if (isPrime == 0) {
            return false;

        }
        else{
            return true;
        }
```

Both work correctly but I cannot understand the logic behind the change NetBeans is suggesting. Neither true or false is being returned. Could someone explain to me the logic behind this? Thanks

Comment: and to be frank: There is nothing wrong about that. It's describing what you want to express. But imagine 10 conditions such as that in a row, than you have 70 lines of code instead of 1. As long as the conditions you are testing are simple comparsions you should stay with the short cut notation. You will get used to read them as quickly as the above example and even read them much quicker after a while.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of

```
if (isPrime == 0) {
    return false;
} else {
    return true;
}
```

try

```
return (isPrime != 0);
```

It is the same thing, I'll show you the refactoring path.  Starting with

```
if (isPrime == 0) {
    return false;
} else {
    return true;
}
```

is the same as

```
if (isPrime != 0) {
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}
```

which can be reduced by substitution, substituting 'isPrime != 0' with the function 'doIsPrime()'

```
private boolean doIsPrime() {
   return isPrime != 0;
}
```

substituting in

```
if (doIsPrime()) {
    // guaranteed to be the same as above!
    return doIsPrime();
} else {
    return doIsPrime();
}
```

which can have both blocks reduced (as duplicated code)

```
if (doIsPrime()) {
}
return doIsPrime();
```

And reduced further by removing the if statement around the empty block

```
return doIsPrime();
```

Now undo the substitution 'doIsPrime()' back to 'isPrime != 0'

```
return isPrime != 0;
```

There was no need to really do the substitution; but, I find it better shows off the reasoning the if statement is redundant.

Comment: Haha, beautiful explanation. Like it!

Answer (score 4):

NetBeans is exactly correct.  The expression *is* a boolean.  You can easily prove it by making the change and trying it.

What value does `0 != 0` evaluate to?  (Hint: it's `false`).  What about `1 != 0`?  (Hint: it's `true`).

Is that not what your more verbose code says?

Comment: Doesn't it rather return a boolean?

Comment: Those are boolean expressions.  What are you asking?

Comment: Thanks duffymo I'm getting used to Java right now and trying to understand the logic behind short cuts in coding.

Comment: I wouldn't say that an expression is a boolean. I'd say it evaluates to a boolean and that boolean is a data type. But I'm not a native speaker.

Answer (score 1):

> Neither true or false is being returned.

False.  The result of the comparison `isPrime != 0`, a `boolean` is being returned, either `true` or `false`.

> Could someone explain to me the logic behind this?

The first code is equivalent to the second code.  If `isPrime` is `0`, then return `false`, else return `true`.  The `!=` operator will yield `false` if `isPrime` is `0`, and `true` if it isn't `0`.

Answer (score 1):

It means its returning the result of the predicat `isPrime != 0`
If isPrime = 0, then the predicat is false, therefore it return false
If isPrime != 0, then the predicat is true, therefore returning true

Answer (score 0):

It's just to reduce code.

The expression `isPrime != 0` returns a boolean. It is false if `isPrime == 0` and true if `isPrime != 0`. Thus you can save the if statement and some lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

*Just to add to what's already said:*

Though your solution and NetBeans recommended approach are exactly correct, one other approach would also be:

```
if (isPrime == 0) {
    return false;
}

return true;
```

I don't know what NetBeans would suggest with this approach but I guess that it would propose the same recommendation as it did above.